# Proof that f is convex

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Consider $D\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ a convex set and $f_i:D\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ convex functions in $D$, $i \in I$ is a any set of indexes. Suppose there is $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f_i(x)\leq\beta$ for all $x\in D$ and $i\in D$. Proof that function $f(x)=\sup f_i(x)$ is convex in $D$.

I tried to do using the convex definition and some properties of sup. But nothing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take any $x,y\in D$ and $u,v\geq 0 \wedge u+v=1$ then $$f_i (ux+vy)\leq uf_i (x) +vf_i (y) \leq u\sup_i f_i (x) +v \sup_i f_i (y)$$ hence $$\sup_i f_i (ux+vy) \leq u\sup_i f_i (x) +v \sup_i f_i (y)$$

Comment: Awesome!!! I did it, but I thought it had forced the result. Thank you, @MotylaNogaTomkaMazura.